# How to use dynamic select on Select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I want to select grouped Country using `Select2`, based on first `select`. I'm trying with basic `Select2` code, but the second `select` with `data-group` is not working properly.

My issue is:

> Changing the first `select` (Continents) option, then move to second (Countries) and choose a country, now back to Continents and change to another. Go to second and choose another Country, it won't select.

*Example*: Choose Europe > Choose Italy > Choose America > Choose Argentina > Choose Europe Again > Choose any Country > Argentina will stay as selected country.

Here's a small video showing the problem happening: [Youtube Link](http://youtube.com/watch?v=8GgZcg33HJw&feature=youtu.be)

I also attached my working code on the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});

$(function(){
    $('#groups').on('change', function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        var sub = $('#sub_groups');
        $('option', sub).filter(function(){
            if (
                 $(this).attr('data-group') === val 
              || $(this).attr('data-group') === 'SHOW'
            ) {
              if ($(this).parent('span').length) {
                $(this).unwrap();
              }
            } else {
              if (!$(this).parent('span').length) {
                $(this).wrap( "<span>" ).parent().hide();
              }
            }
        });
    });
    $('#groups').trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select class="js-example-basic-single" id="groups" style="width:50%;">
    <option value='America'>America</option>
    <option value='Europe'>Europe</option>
    <option value='Asia'>Asia</option>
<select>
    
<select class="js-example-basic-single" id="sub_groups" style="width:50%;">
    <option data-group='SHOW' value='0'>-- Select --</option>
    <option data-group='America' value='Argentina'>Argentina</option>
    <option data-group='America' value='Brazil'>Brazil</option>
    <option data-group='America' value='Chile'>Chile</option>
    <option data-group='Europe' value='Italy'>Italy</option>
    <option data-group='Europe' value='France'>France</option>
    <option data-group='Europe' value='Spain'>Spain</option>
    <option data-group='Asia' value='China'>China</option>
    <option data-group='Asia' value='Japan'>Japan</option>
<select>
```

Is there any solution to that problem?

Comment: Sorry, but I cant see anything wrong, what I'm missing? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Have you tried the code after running my code on the snippet @CalvinNunes? After first selected, and move to another continent (ie. from America to Europe) there's won't work properly on the country / second option.

Comment: I've edited my question (y)

Comment: I select 'Asia', then the second option shows me: China and Japan. I select 'America', then the second option shows: Argentina, Brazil, Chile.  What's wrong here? (tested after edit)

Comment: here is what I meant : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GgZcg33HJw&feature=youtu.be

I've select Europe and Italy as selected Country, but after I try to move to Asia, and want to select Japan or China, there's is not working properly.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the problem, but didn't find solution yet (I edited your question to let it more clear to understand) Maybe someone can help now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset `sub_groups`' value to 0 when `groups` is changed.

```
$('#groups').on('change', function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  var sub = $('#sub_groups');
  sub.val(0);
  ...
});
```

Also as a side note, the `select` tags in your HTML aren't closed properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});

$(function() {
  $('#groups').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var sub = $('#sub_groups');
    sub.val(0);
    $('option', sub).filter(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('data-group') === val ||
          $(this).attr('data-group') === 'SHOW') {
        if ($(this).parent('span').length) {
          $(this).unwrap();
        }
      } else {
        if (!$(this).parent('span').length) {
          $(this).wrap("<span>").parent().hide();
        }
      }
    });
  });
  $('#groups').trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="js-example-basic-single" id="groups" style="width:50%;">
  <option value='America'>America</option>
  <option value='Europe'>Europe</option>
  <option value='Asia'>Asia</option>
</select>

<select class="js-example-basic-single" id="sub_groups" style="width:50%;">
  <option data-group='SHOW' value='0'>-- Select --</option>
  <option data-group='America' value='Argentina'>Argentina</option>
  <option data-group='America' value='Brazil'>Brazil</option>
  <option data-group='America' value='Chile'>Chile</option>
  <option data-group='Europe' value='Italy'>Italy</option>
  <option data-group='Europe' value='France'>France</option>
  <option data-group='Europe' value='Spain'>Spain</option>
  <option data-group='Asia' value='China'>China</option>
  <option data-group='Asia' value='Japan'>Japan</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thats brilliant idea, but if I added the default selected value won't work.

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: for example :
`<option data-group='America' value='Brazil' selected>Brazil</option>`

the default selection are not displaying there.

Comment: If you want to select Brazil by default, just add `$('#sub_groups').val('Brazil');` after `$('#groups').trigger('change');`.

Comment: Woaa.. It so amazing. 100% worked. Thanks @Joseph Webber you've save my time :)
I also already mark your aswer as accepted :)